# Simultaneous vector equations - dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R^3}$ be vectors satisfying $x+y=2a$ and $x\cdot y=c$, where $c<a\cdot a$. How can we solve these equations simultaneously? Obviously we can't manipulate the terms in the same way as for a non-vector equation, but I wonder if we can dot both sides with $y$ to eliminate terms?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(x_1\ x_2\ x_3)$ and $y=(y_1\ y_2\ y_3)$, then $a=\left(\frac{x_1+y_1}{2}\ \frac{x_2+y_2}{2}\ \frac{x_3+y_3}{2}\right)$. Then $x\cdot y=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3=c$. And $a.a=\left(\frac{x_1+y_1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x_2+y_2}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x_3+y_3}{2}\right)^2$. By AM-GM inequality obviously we have $c\le a\cdot a$.

Comment: Thanks! How could we find specific vectors $x,y$ from this?

Comment: Depends on $c$. If $c$ is zero then take two orthogonal vectors. If $c\ne0$, then neither $x$ nor $y$ can be the zero vector. Choose any non-zero $x$. Then there is at least one component of $x$, that is non-zero, let it be $x_1$. Let $y_2$ and $y_3$ be any real values. This determines the value of $y_1$ as $(c-x_2y_2-x_3y_3)/x_1$.